# How to flip axis in xmgrace?

Tags: xmgrace

I have a graph and I just want to rotate it 90°, which could be accomplished if I could flip the x and y axis.
How can I do it? I have no experience in using xmgrace via terminal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- **Step 1**: Click “Data” from the menu bar. Select “Transformations.” Then select “Geometric transforms…”
- **Step 2**: Select the set(s) or “All sets.” Enter “90.0” in the “Rotation (degrees)” field. Enter “-1.0” in the “Scale X” field.
- **Step 3**: Click Accept. Click Close.
- **Step 4**: Autoscale graph (one can use the “AS” tab from the toolbar).

Note: This works on Grace-5.1.25. You could play with the “Geometric transform…” fields by entering different values, if you want to, to get your desired results.

PS: I learned this trick from my advisor.

Comment: Is this possible to use these steps in command line? When I make a parameter file (.par) in the figure of vertical axis (rotation of 90 degree), it cannot be applied to new plot with $xmgrace ... -p a.par.

Answer (score 2):

It is very easy and the logic of the steps goes like this. Create a new set with flipped axis and update the set for further analysis. I also added in step 5 to autoscale the two axes, you can omit that step if you think otherwise.

In `xmgrace` window, go to

1. <kbd>Data</kbd> → <kbd>Transformations</kbd> → <kbd>Evaluate expression</kbd>.
2. Click on the parent set to be represented as flipped axes, lets assume it is `S0`.
3. In the `formula` section, write `s1.x=s0.y; s1.y=s0.x` and click <kbd>apply</kbd>. This will create a new set `S1` which is the flipped axes representation of `S0`.
4. Click on <kbd>View</kbd> →  <kbd>Update all</kbd> and then <kbd>View</kbd> →  <kbd>Redraw</kbd>. This will update and draw the newly created set for further analysis.
5. On main window, click on <kbd>Edit</kbd> →  <kbd>autoscale graphs...</kbd>. This will autoscale the two graphs.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to treat multiple sets at once this trick could work:

x = y*x; y=x/y; x=x/y

Make sure that your original y has nonzero values.